# How to set cookies in phantomjs using selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, phantomjs

[image]

It raise an error message said "Can only set Cookies for the current domain",but all I did is just put the old cookies in.Sometime I add the 'correct' domain,it will raise error Message "Unable to set Cookie".
And I tested it in Firefox,Firefox also cant work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantompath)
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('1.png')
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get_cookies()
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PhantomJS driver doesn't support all the keys from the cookie dictionary. One way to overcome this issue is to select the keys:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')

cookies = driver.get_cookies()

driver.delete_all_cookies()

for cookie in cookies :
    driver.add_cookie({k: cookie[k] for k in ('name', 'value', 'domain', 'path', 'expiry')})
```

Comment: It is available in stackoverflow website,but it can't work in other website.So does it have a common way to overcom this issue?

Comment: It works with other websites. Note that you first need to set the domain with `driver.get('http://...')` before calling `driver.add_cookie` and make sure that domain of the cookie is the same as the one from the current page.

Comment: Yeah,I run this code without error,but when I changed `driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')` to `driver.get('https://github.com/')`  ,it will raise `KeyError: 'expiry'`.And it will raise `"errorMessage":"Unable to set Cookie"` in other websites,

Comment: I would remove the domain and check that the key exists: `driver.add_cookie({k: cookie[k] for k in ('name', 'value', 'path', 'expiry') if k in cookie})`

Comment: I remove the 'domain' as what you do,but this code can't correctly process the 'https://github.com/' website yet,it raises `"errorMessage":"Can only set Cookies for the current domain"`

Comment: I've just tested this example with `.get('https://github.com/login')` and without the `domain` key. I don't get any exception and the cookies are created as expected.

Comment: Note that you cannot insert cookies from a domain that is different from the current page domain. You need to call `.get("http...")` first to set the domain.

Comment: Actually I always call .get('http...') before add cookies.Here is the total code: `from selenium import webdriver
phantompath='C:\\code\\browser\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantompath)
driver.get('https://github.com/login')
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
print(cookies)
driver.delete_all_cookies()

for cookie in cookies :
    driver.add_cookie({k: cookie[k] for k in ('name', 'value' , 'path','expiry')})`After I press F5 key, it will raise "errorMessage":"Can only set Cookies for the current domain"

Comment: The `delete_all_cookies` part was really useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the domain parameter for each cookie. The domain field must be formatted like this:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.baidu.com')
driver.delete_all_cookies()

for item in cookie_dictionary: 
    driver.add_cookie({
      'domain': '.baidu.com', # note the dot at the beginning
      'name': item['name'],
      'value': item['value'],
      'path': '/',
      'expires': None
    })

driver.get('http://www.baidu.com')
```

Comment: @Pedro Castilho Thanks

Comment: As an addition to @HiddenStrawberry's answer above, the dot/period infront of the domain is required even for values such as `localhost` - as I found out the hard way.

Chrome and Firefox drivers would add the cookie with the domain set to `localhost` but the PhantomJS driver would only successfully add the cookie if the domain was set to `.localhost`.